# How to deallocate in a polymorphic way in Fortran 2003?

Tags: class, memory-management, fortran, final, fortran2003

Before trying to implement a user-derived type hierarchy, I am trying to understand polymorphic deallocation using Fortran 2003 features. The ideal goal is to figure out how to deallocate a declared-parent-type pointer that may point to any other compatible child types.

As the following code show, the file `liboo.f90` declares a base type `Parent` and an inherited type `Child`. Both types have `FINAL` for both scalar and array situtations, respectively. The file `test_liboo.f90` tries different deallocation using 18 different subroutines.

The subroutines `TestParent_3_POINTER_CLASS`, `TestParent_7_array_POINTER_CLASS`, 
`TestChild_3_POINTER_CLASS`, `TestChild_7_array_POINTER_CLASS`,
`TestPolymorph_3_array_Pointer_TypeForChildren_ClassForParents`, 
`TestPolymorph_4_array_Pointer_ClassForChildren_ClassForParents`, all give segmentation faults. The error messages of `TestParent_3_POINTER_CLASS` is shown below.

The subroutines `TestPolymorph_1_Pointer_TypeForChild_ClassForParent` says `forrtl: severe (173): A pointer passed to DEALLOCATE points to an array that cannot be deallocated`.

Could you help to comment the reasons?

`TestPolymorph_2_Pointer_ClassForChild_ClassForParent` does not give segmentation fault, but only invoke Child's `Final`, while `TestChild_1` and and so forth can invoke both Child's `Final` and Parent's `Final`, which should be desirable.

I am wondering how to deallocate a declared-parent-type that actually holds an inherited type in Fortran 2003? Any insights will be appreciated!

PS: The compiler is Intel Fortran Compiler, and the version is as the follows:

```
[root@localhost new]# ifort --version
ifort (IFORT) 12.1.0 20111011
Copyright (C) 1985-2011 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

### One of the error messages

```
[root@localhost new]# make clean
rm -rf liboo.mod liboo.o test_liboo.o test_liboo
[root@localhost new]# make
ifort -c -O0 -check -g -traceback  -openmp liboo.f90
ifort -c -O0 -check -g -traceback  -openmp test_liboo.f90
ifort -o test_liboo liboo.o test_liboo.o -static  -openmp 
[root@localhost new]# ./test_liboo
 TestParent_1 begins.
 DestroyParent
 TestParent_1 ends.

 TestParent_2_POINTER_TYPE begins.
 DestroyParent
 TestParent_2_POINTER_TYPE ends.

 TestParent_3_POINTER_CLASS begins.
 DestroyParent
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
test_liboo         0000000000404B9C  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
test_liboo         0000000000404A9F  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
test_liboo         0000000000401ED5  test_liboo_IP_tes         140  test_liboo.f90
test_liboo         0000000000400829  MAIN__                     20  test_liboo.f90
test_liboo         00000000004002EC  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
test_liboo         00000000004F4B90  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
test_liboo         00000000004001B9  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
[root@localhost new]#
```

### Makefile

```
# Compiler
 FC            = ifort
# Linker
 LINKER        = ${FC}
# Compiler flags  
 FCFLAGS       = -c -O0 -check -g -traceback 
 FCFLAGS2      = -openmp
# Linker flags
 FLFLAGS       = -static 
 FLFLAGS2      = -openmp
# Utilities
 RM            = rm -rf
 ECHO          = echo
 SHELL         = /bin/sh


# clear out all suffixes
.SUFFIXES:
# list only those we use
.SUFFIXES: .o .f90 .f


# define a suffix rule for .f90 -> .o
.f90.o:
    ${FC} ${FCFLAGS} ${FCFLAGS2} $<


# define a suffix rule for .f -> .o
.f.o:
    ${FC} ${FCFLAGS} ${FCFLAGS2} $<


#
test_liboo: liboo.o test_liboo.o
    ${LINKER} -o test_liboo liboo.o test_liboo.o ${FLFLAGS} ${FLFLAGS2} 


#
clean:
    ${RM} liboo.mod liboo.o test_liboo.o test_liboo
```

### liboo.f90

```
!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**
    MODULE LibOO

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7** 
        TYPE :: Parent
          INTEGER :: a    
        CONTAINS
            FINAL :: DestroyParent
            FINAL :: DestroyParents
        END TYPE

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7** 
        TYPE, EXTENDS (Parent) :: child 
            INTEGER :: b
        CONTAINS
            FINAL :: DestroyChild
            FINAL :: DestroyChildren
        END TYPE

    CONTAINS

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**    
        SUBROUTINE DestroyParent(this)

        TYPE(Parent) :: this

        WRITE (*,*) 'DestroyParent'

        END SUBROUTINE

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**    
        SUBROUTINE DestroyParents(this)

        TYPE(Parent), DIMENSION(:) :: this

        WRITE (*,*) 'DestroyParents'

        END SUBROUTINE

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**    
        SUBROUTINE DestroyChild(this)

        TYPE(Child) :: this

        WRITE (*,*) 'DestroyChild'

        END SUBROUTINE

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**    
        SUBROUTINE DestroyChildren(this)

        TYPE(Child), DIMENSION(:) :: this

        WRITE (*,*) 'DestroyChildren'

        END SUBROUTINE

    END MODULE
!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**
```

### test_liboo.f90

```
!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**
    PROGRAM test_liboo

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**  

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestParent_1 begins.'
    CALL TestParent_1
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestParent_1 ends.'
    READ (*,*)

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestParent_2_POINTER_TYPE begins.'
    CALL TestParent_2_POINTER_TYPE
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestParent_2_POINTER_TYPE ends.'
    READ (*,*)

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestParent_3_POINTER_CLASS begins.'
    CALL TestParent_3_POINTER_CLASS
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestParent_3_POINTER_CLASS ends.'
    READ (*,*)

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestParent_4_array begins.'
    CALL TestParent_4_array
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestParent_4_array ends.'
    READ (*,*)

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestParent_5_array_ALLOCATABLE begins.'
    CALL TestParent_5_array_ALLOCATABLE
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestParent_5_array_ALLOCATABLE ends.'
    READ (*,*)

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestParent_6_array_POINTER_TYPE begins.'
    CALL TestParent_6_array_POINTER_TYPE
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestParent_6_array_POINTER_TYPE ends.'
    READ (*,*)

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestParent_7_array_POINTER_CLASS begins.'
    CALL TestParent_7_array_POINTER_CLASS
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestParent_7_array_POINTER_CLASS ends.'
    READ (*,*)

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**  

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestChild_1 begins.'
    CALL TestChild_1
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestChild_1 ends.'
    READ (*,*)

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestChild_2_POINTER_TYPE begins.'
    CALL TestChild_2_POINTER_TYPE
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestChild_2_POINTER_TYPE ends.'
    READ (*,*)

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestChild_3_POINTER_CLASS begins.'
    CALL TestChild_3_POINTER_CLASS
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestChild_3_POINTER_CLASS ends.'
    READ (*,*)

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestChild_4_array begins.'
    CALL TestChild_4_array
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestChild_4_array ends.'
    READ (*,*)

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestChild_5_array_ALLOCATABLE begins.'
    CALL TestChild_5_array_ALLOCATABLE
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestChild_5_array_ALLOCATABLE ends.'
    READ (*,*)

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestChild_6_array_POINTER_TYPE begins.'
    CALL TestChild_6_array_POINTER_TYPE
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestChild_6_array_POINTER_TYPE ends.'
    READ (*,*)

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestChild_7_array_POINTER_CLASS begins.'
    CALL TestChild_7_array_POINTER_CLASS
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestChild_7_array_POINTER_CLASS ends.'
    READ (*,*)

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**  

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestPolymorph_1_Pointer_TypeForChild_ClassForParent begins.'
    CALL TestPolymorph_1_Pointer_TypeForChild_ClassForParent
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestPolymorph_1_Pointer_TypeForChild_ClassForParent ends.'
    READ (*,*)

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestPolymorph_2_Pointer_ClassForChild_ClassForParent begins.'
    CALL TestPolymorph_2_Pointer_ClassForChild_ClassForParent
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestPolymorph_2_Pointer_ClassForChild_ClassForParent ends.'
    READ (*,*)

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestPolymorph_3_array_Pointer_TypeForChildren_ClassForParents begins.'
    CALL TestPolymorph_3_array_Pointer_TypeForChildren_ClassForParents
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestPolymorph_3_array_Pointer_TypeForChildren_ClassForParents ends.'
    READ (*,*)

    WRITE (*,*) 'TestPolymorph_4_array_Pointer_ClassForChildren_ClassForParents begins.'
    CALL TestPolymorph_4_array_Pointer_ClassForChildren_ClassForParents
    WRITE (*,*) 'TestPolymorph_4_array_Pointer_ClassForChildren_ClassForParents ends.'
    READ (*,*)

    CONTAINS

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**    
    SUBROUTINE TestParent_1

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

    TYPE(Parent) :: myParent
    myParent%a = 6

    END SUBROUTINE TestParent_1

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**
    SUBROUTINE TestParent_2_POINTER_TYPE

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

    TYPE(Parent), POINTER :: pMyParent

    ALLOCATE(pMyParent)
    pMyParent%a = 6
    DEALLOCATE(pMyParent)

    END SUBROUTINE TestParent_2_POINTER_TYPE

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**
    SUBROUTINE TestParent_3_POINTER_CLASS

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

    CLASS(Parent), POINTER :: pMyParent

    ALLOCATE(pMyParent)
    pMyParent%a = 6
    DEALLOCATE(pMyParent)

    END SUBROUTINE TestParent_3_POINTER_CLASS

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**
    SUBROUTINE TestParent_4_array

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

    TYPE(Parent), DIMENSION(3) :: myParents
    myParents(1)%a = 6

    END SUBROUTINE TestParent_4_array

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**
    SUBROUTINE TestParent_5_array_ALLOCATABLE

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

    TYPE(Parent), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: myParents

    ALLOCATE(myParents(3))
    myParents(1)%a = 6
    DEALLOCATE(myParents)

    END SUBROUTINE TestParent_5_array_ALLOCATABLE

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**
    SUBROUTINE TestParent_6_array_POINTER_TYPE

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

    TYPE(Parent), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: pMyParents

    ALLOCATE(pMyParents(3))
    pMyParents(1)%a = 6
    DEALLOCATE(pMyParents)

    END SUBROUTINE TestParent_6_array_POINTER_TYPE

 !***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**
    SUBROUTINE TestParent_7_array_POINTER_CLASS

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

    CLASS(Parent), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: pMyParents

    ALLOCATE(pMyParents(3))
    pMyParents(1)%a = 6
    DEALLOCATE(pMyParents)

    END SUBROUTINE TestParent_7_array_POINTER_CLASS

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**    
    SUBROUTINE TestChild_1

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

    TYPE(child) :: myChild
    myChild%b = 6

    END SUBROUTINE TestChild_1

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**
    SUBROUTINE TestChild_2_POINTER_TYPE

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

    TYPE(child), POINTER :: pMyChild

    ALLOCATE(pMyChild)
    pMyChild%b = 6
    DEALLOCATE(pMyChild)

    END SUBROUTINE TestChild_2_POINTER_TYPE

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**
    SUBROUTINE TestChild_3_POINTER_CLASS

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

    CLASS(child), POINTER :: pMyChild

    ALLOCATE(pMyChild)
    pMyChild%b = 6
    DEALLOCATE(pMyChild)

    END SUBROUTINE TestChild_3_POINTER_CLASS

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**    
    SUBROUTINE TestChild_4_array

    USE LibOO 
    IMPLICIT NONE

    TYPE(child), DIMENSION(3) :: myChild
    myChild(1)%b = 6

    END SUBROUTINE TestChild_4_array

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**    
    SUBROUTINE TestChild_5_array_ALLOCATABLE

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

    TYPE(child), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: myChildren
    ALLOCATE(myChildren(3))
    myChildren(1)%b = 6
    DEALLOCATE(myChildren)

    END SUBROUTINE TestChild_5_array_ALLOCATABLE

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**    
    SUBROUTINE TestChild_6_array_POINTER_TYPE

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

    TYPE(child), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: pMyChildren

    ALLOCATE(pMyChildren(3))
    pMyChildren(1)%b = 6
    DEALLOCATE(pMyChildren)

    END SUBROUTINE TestChild_6_array_POINTER_TYPE

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**    
    SUBROUTINE TestChild_7_array_POINTER_CLASS

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

    CLASS(child), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: pMyChildren

    ALLOCATE(pMyChildren(3))
    pMyChildren(1)%b = 6
    DEALLOCATE(pMyChildren)

    END SUBROUTINE TestChild_7_array_POINTER_CLASS

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**    
    SUBROUTINE TestPolymorph_1_Pointer_TypeForChild_ClassForParent

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

    TYPE(child), POINTER :: pMyChild
    CLASS(parent), POINTER :: pMyParent

    ALLOCATE(pMyChild)
    pMyChild%b = 6
    pMyParent => pMyChild
    DEALLOCATE(pMyParent)

    END SUBROUTINE TestPolymorph_1_Pointer_TypeForChild_ClassForParent

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**    
    SUBROUTINE TestPolymorph_2_Pointer_ClassForChild_ClassForParent

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

    CLASS(child), POINTER :: pMyChild
    CLASS(parent), POINTER :: pMyParent

    ALLOCATE(pMyChild)
    pMyChild%b = 6
    pMyParent => pMyChild
    DEALLOCATE(pMyParent)

    END SUBROUTINE TestPolymorph_2_Pointer_ClassForChild_ClassForParent

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**    
    SUBROUTINE TestPolymorph_3_array_Pointer_TypeForChildren_ClassForParents

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

    TYPE(child), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: pMyChildren
    CLASS(parent), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: pMyParents

    ALLOCATE(pMyChildren(3))
    pMyChildren(1)%b = 6
    pMyParents => pMyChildren
    DEALLOCATE(pMyParents)

    END SUBROUTINE TestPolymorph_3_array_Pointer_TypeForChildren_ClassForParents

!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**    
    SUBROUTINE TestPolymorph_4_array_Pointer_ClassForChildren_ClassForParents

    USE LibOO
    IMPLICIT NONE

    CLASS(child), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: pMyChildren
    CLASS(parent), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: pMyParents

    ALLOCATE(pMyChildren(3))
    pMyChildren(1)%b = 6
    pMyParents => pMyChildren
    DEALLOCATE(pMyParents)

    END SUBROUTINE TestPolymorph_4_array_Pointer_ClassForChildren_ClassForParents

    END PROGRAM test_liboo
!***|****1****|****2****|****3****|****4****|****5****|****6****|****7**
```

Comment: SORRY, BUT IT IS REALLY HARD TO READ YOUR CODE WITH CAPS AND NO INDENTING, BUT I WILL GIVE A TRY.

Comment: I don't know, but without the finalization procedures, all the nonarray tests work well for gfortran and Solaris Studio. No segmentation faults are generated and valgrind didn't find any memory leaks.

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you very much for your precious time and efforts! Even though `but without the finalization procedures, ...,valgrind didn't find any memory leaks.`, could the reason be that there is no complexity of additional pointer/allocatable components of the user-derived types? I wish I could follow the best practice of using OO style in fortran. PS: sorry for the trouble concerning CAPS! Really confused which coding style of which book to follow...

Answer (score 6):

You aren't doing anything wrong - the version of Intel Fortran you're using has a bug. I reproduced it in the current version (13.1.3), but not in the latest beta of 14.0, so it looks as if the bug has been fixed. The new version is due out early September.

Comment: Thanks - not sure why I never looked into StackOverflow before.... I hope to be helpful here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful comment! I will try the 14 version to check!